# Selection of Component - Apps vs WebPart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin

I am planning to build up a UI which will call a SOAP based Web Services. I am totally new to SharePoint, will a web part or app which one will be best suit for the scenario.

I will be using SharePoint 2013. All I need a UI which need to be running out of SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your UI outside of SharePoint and your data is coming from custom web services then you probably want to go with a Provider-Hosted App. I say probably because there are many factors that need to be considered when making this decision.

As an aside, learning how to do SharePoint development is going to take some time. To just learn the fundamentals could take a few months. You should consider this while planning for this project.